# How to access multi-item index model in Views of Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, composite-primary-key

I have a Django model with a 3 item index.

```
class Url(models.Model):
    word1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    word2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    word3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #more fields here

    class Meta:
        indexes= [models.Index(fields=['word1','word2','word3'])]
```

This item is called by a url that contains the index values in my url.py (I think I did this right, still sorta a noobie with django)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeView.as_view()),
    path('<str:word1>.<str:word2>.<str:word3>',views.redirect)
]
```

But how do I actually load the individual model from my database into my view function for a multi-index entry?

```
def redirect(request,word1,word2,word3):
    # just load one db entry instead of  url = Url.objects.all()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('someother.variablefrom.mymodel')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
def redirect(request,word1,word2,word3):
    url = Url.objects.filter(word1=word1, word2=word2, word3=word3).first()  # for one db entry,
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, but is there also a good way to set a default in case the filter fails?

Comment: that's weird, you had edits that showed up and then disappeared right away

Comment: ya, removed the same content that i had added. After your comment, i thought that content wasn't needed.

Comment: you can define a default url if the queryset is None.